# Upgrade problem from 2.1.4 to 2.1.6

Tags: magento-2.1, upgrade

I'm trying to update Magento from 2.1.4 to 2.1.6 using composer.
But I'm getting this error:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.2 -> no matching package found.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please do `composer update colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract` first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured out what was wrong. The issue was with composer credentials (I used EE instead of community credentials), this can be changed in `.composer/auth.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Install missing package first as follows.

```
composer require colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.2 --no-update
composer update
```

Then try to update again using composer.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but got errors: Problem 1
    - The requested package colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.2 exists as colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.1] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Comment: Problem 2
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.1.3, required as 2.1.6) is satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: Can you paste that error ?

Comment: Problem 3
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.6].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.6 requires colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract 1.2 -> no matching package found.

Comment: Run:   composer update colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract

Comment: The same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps from below url

```
http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/magento2/9022/upgrading-magento#t=201704130958117574309
```

I have tested it from 2.1.4 to 2.1.6 and it worked perfectly fine.